# Regarding Url's name and why?

Tags: node.js, pdf, url, https

i have been go through alot and alot of SO, forum....

But i dont have an idea... what is the different between this 2 URL.

```
https://tanningyou.testrail.io/index.php?/reports/view/1, 
https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf
```

Both of them can let me download a pdf... but why i use https get request.. i unable to get the docs.testrail.io...'s pdf file? i can get the w3.org...'s pdf file.

May i ask what is this URL call? https://tanningyou.testrail.io/index.php?/reports/view/1 . From this URL when i open with incognito. It will redirect the URL link to login page.

And how can i use nodejs https to get this pdf from docs.testrail.io... url link?

Why are them so different?

So far i had tried.

```
var username = 'username@gmail.com';
var password = '123456789';
var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
console.log("auth", auth)
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'tanningyou.testrail.io',
  port: 443,
  path: '/index.php?/reports/view/1',
  method: 'GET',
  Authorization: auth
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(************************************************************************************************************statusCode: ${res.statusCode})

    res.on('data', d => {
        console.log("************************************************d", d)
        process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error("**************************************************************************",error)
})

req.end()
```

Comment: you need to show your code at the very least.

Comment: @Jarede so far what i tried i show in the question already. But i did not managed to get from testrail.... but for the w3.org link i can get the pdf content.